# How to bind mailto to this PushButton onclick action in PDF form?

Tags: hyperref, forms, email

I want to send email with the action of the link in the pdf form. 
I added `action=mailto:...` into the `PushButton`, after `onclick` but I am not sure if you should bind `mailto` on the `onclick` somehow directly.
Code

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388186/13173
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386853/13173
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[charsize={10pt},multiline=true,height={5mm},width={5cm},name={text_info},bordercolor={0.2 0.2 0.7},default={}]{}
\PushButton[onclick={this.exportAsText()},action=mailto:leo <leo.test@mailinator.com>]{Submit}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Output in compiling with `pdflatex`

```
 ! Package kvsetkeys Error: Undefined key `action'.
```

### Testing diabonas' proposal

1. Diabonas' example code works, but controlling the email content better next step: send the file itself and textual content in the email.
2. Works in Beamer too with the following example

Beamer code example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage{microtype}% more flexibility for narrow columns
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395124/13173
\RequirePackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{eforms}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Lorem}
Testing 1. 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
% Show reproduction of the answers in the next sheet. 

Send to the address:
\begin{Form}
\TextField[charsize={10pt},multiline=true,height={5mm},width={5cm},name={text_info},bordercolor={0.2 0.2 0.7},default={}]{}
\PushButton[onclick={this.submitForm("mailto:leo <leo.test@mailinator.com>"); this.exportAsText();}]{Submit}
\end{Form}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output: activation of email client

OS: Debian 9.1
TeXLive: 2017
Email client: Thunderbird
PDF viewer: Adobe Reader (acroread in Linux)

Comment: `action` is a `Form` environment option, but not  a `\PushButton` option

Comment: @ChristianHupfer How can bind action on the button? Indirectly?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand this question: if you want to send the form data by mail, that's already described in [How to design LaTeX form with user input for data extraction?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386853/3323). The button with the JavaScript action from [Save PDF form information](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388186/3323) is only necessary if you want to *save* the data locally instead of sending it.

Comment: @diabonas I want to do both - save locally and send by email.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: I suppose it is possible with some JavaScript wizardry. Other's have experience with that, but not me

Comment: Just saw that @diabonas mentioned JavaScript already

Answer (score 5):

In order to both send the form by email and save the data to a file locally, you can use the `submitForm` JavaScript method:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[charsize={10pt},multiline=true,height={5mm},width={5cm},name={text_info},bordercolor={0.2 0.2 0.7},default={}]{}
\PushButton[onclick={this.submitForm({cURL: "mailto:leo <leo.test@mailinator.com>", cSubmitAs: "FDF"); this.exportAsText();}]{Submit}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

This works sequentially, i.e. you will be prompted to save the file to disk only after you have sent the email (or at least closed the compose window).

Theoretically you could switch the order of the JavaScript commands to save the file first, but I would recommend doing it in the order given here: the free Adobe Reader only supports sending the data, but not saving it, so with this approach, it will at least send the form, while it will throw an error and do nothing at all the other way round.

The data sent by mail will be in the [FDF file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Forms_Data_Format_.28FDF.29) by default. You can change it to a more parser-friendly XML-based format by changing the `cSubmitAs` parameter of the `submitForm` method to [`XFDF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#XML_Forms_Data_Format_.28XFDF.29). Export in [query string syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is also supported with the parameter value `HTML`, but it seems to get blocked by the Microsoft Outlook email client, so I wouldn't recommend using it. The [JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/AcrobatDC_js_api_reference.pdf#page=346) also lists a few other, more uncommon data formats.

The data saved to a file will be in [CSV file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), and can be changed to FDF or XFDF as described in [Save PDF form information](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388186/3323).

Comment: This action sends an email with the title `test.email_data.fdf` to the email address, without the file itself. How can you decide what the `onclick` action send? It seems to `exportAsText` there.  - - Can you reproduce your solution in Beamer? I cannot get it work there, please see the body for Beamer example.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 That sounds like a problem with your viewer or email client, what software are you using? I tested it successfully on Windows using both Adobe Acrobat and Adobe Reader (the latter can only send the email, not save the form data) in combination with Thunderbird and Outlook. Your `beamer` example works fine for me by simply replacing the `\PushButton` in your MWE by the one given in this answer.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Regarding the data format the `submitForm` JavaScript sends, that would be FDF by default, you can change it using to XFDF or query string syntax by using `this.submitForm({cURL: "mailto:leo <leo.test@mailinator.com>", cSubmitAs: "XFDF"})` or `this.submitForm({cURL: "mailto:leo <leo.test@mailinator.com>", cSubmitAs: "HTML"})`, respectively.

Comment: I am using Thunderbird as email client. It works in article documentclass, but not in Beamer. - - Yes, I confirm that Adobe Reader can activate the email client in my system too with article documentclass.

Comment: @diabonas you forgot a brace at the line with ``\PushButton``.

Comment: @diabonas Neither XFDF nor FDF works for the key ``cSubmitAs``.